# Having trouble with an Inductive proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Define O<sub>n</sub> as inductively as follows: O<sub>1</sub> = {1}; O<sub>n+1</sub> = O<sub>n</sub> ∪ {2n+1}. Let O = ∪<sub>n</sub>O<sub>n</sub>. Let O = ∪<sub>n</sub>O<sub>n</sub>

Prove by Induction that O<sub>n</sub> = {1,3,...,2n-1}

---

P(n) would be the statement that O<sub>n+1</sub> = O<sub>n</sub> ∪ {2n+1}.

However, I'm having trouble doing with the base case.

P(1) ( i.e.  O<sub>2</sub> = O<sub>1</sub> ∪ {3}   ) is true because ...

By the definition, isn't O<sub>2</sub> = {2}? and the RHS {1,3}? Surely I'm missing something here?

---

Also, what does a Union symbol with a subscript mean?

Thanks.

Comment: $O_2=O_1\cup \{2\cdot 1 + 1\} = \{1\}\cup \{3\} = \{1,3\}$.  Just because $O_1 = \{1\}$ does not mean that all other $O_i=\{i\}$, so no it is not the case that $O_2=\{2\}$.  As for union symbol with subscript, it is analogous to summation symbols or product symbols with subscripts.  $\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i = A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3\cup \dots \cup A_n$.  Where bounds are not specified, it is assumed to range over all possible values, so in your case, $O = \bigcup_n O_n = O_1\cup O_2\cup O_3\cup \dots$.  You'll have $O$ is the set of all positive odd numbers, while $O_n$ is the set of the first $n$ odd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're working from a not too unusual presentation of induction, $P(n)$ is supposed to be the claim that you want to *prove* holds for all $n$.

Thus, when you say that $P(n)$ means $O_{n+1} = O_n \cup \{2n+1\}$, you're already going wrong, because $O_{n+1} = O_n \cup \{2n+1\}$ is something you *already know to be true*, in that it is your *definition* of what $O_i$ means.

In a proof of $O_n = \{1,3,\ldots,2n-1\}$ by induction on $n$, your $P(n)$ should be that claim:
$$ P(n) \;\equiv\; O_n = \{1,3,\ldots,2n-1\}$$

Even so, you will run into some problems because in order to reason properly about things like $\{1,3,\ldots,2n-1\}$ with dots in them, you need a *definition* for what that notation means. And the most straightforward definition of $\{1,3,5,\ldots,2n-1\}$ would be exactly the recursive definition for $O_n$ you start out with -- but in that case there's nothing at all for you to *prove*!

For class purposes you can probably get away with just winging it and use a non-rigorous intuitive understanding of $\{1,3,\ldots,2n-1\}$ instead of an actual definition. But don't be surprised if it feels like you're not really doing anything ...